# Terminate(end, kill) a specific thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, terminate

I am looking for a way I can kill a thread that I start using an event. I am starting the bot with code as below:

```
 new_thread = threading.Thread(target=info, args=(doc,), name=doc["token"])
 new_thread.start()
```

I have a list where am storing all the threads i start. (I store the threads using the names which are unique UUIDS.

I need to be able to kill a thread using its name. How do I do this? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing threading on your own is not the best solution, it introduces lots of bugs. I found a good solution would be to use task schedulers such as celery click [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) or Huey click [here](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)!